# How to get dynamic suggestions for objects fetched from api in monaco editor?

Tags: antlr, monaco-editor

I've a grammar file for a custom language which my organisation uses, based on which i'm validating the syntax of the code.I want to generate suggestions dynamically based on the objects that i receive from the backend like below in the monaco editor.

I tried finding solutions in monaco's playground examples but there the suggestions are hard coded :[monaco editor example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example)

The docs for monaco-editor seems raw and i couldn't understand the docs well.
It would be highly appreciative if someone guides on how to look at this issue.

[image]

Comment: Your question (which isn't really a question) as it is now, is not likely going to attract answers because it is rather open-ended. Stackoverflow works best if you ask a specific question about a programming related issue you're facing, not something like "can someone assist me write a code editor with auto-complete?"

Comment: What you are looking for is commonly known as "code completion". Search for that in your favourite search engine, together with "antlr4" to get links for possible solutions.